# get one random letter from each tuple then return them all as a string

Tags: scala

3 tuples in a list

```
val l = List(("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f"))
```

choice one element from each tuple then return this 3 letters word every time

for example: fca or afd or cbf ...

how to realize it

the same as:

```
echo {a,b}{c,d}{e,f}|xargs -n1|shuf -n1|sed 's/\B/\n/g'|shuf|paste -sd ''
```

Comment: any one give me help? thx

Comment: Do they have to be tuples? It would be a lot easier if `l` was a `List` of `List` (or even better `Array` of `Array` or  `Vector` of `Vector` for O(1) indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with tuples can be a bit of a pain. You can't easily index them and tuples of different sizes are considered different types in the type system.

```
val ts = List(("a","b"),("c","d"),("e","f"))
val str = ts.map{t =>
  t.productElement(util.Random.nextInt(t.productArity))
}.mkString("")
```

Every time I run this I get a different result: `bde`, `acf`, `bdf`, etc.

Comment: thx.

`val s = List(("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","f"))`


`util.Random.shuffle(s.map{t =>
  t.productElement(util.Random.nextInt(t.productArity))
}).mkString("")`